# How to change date format culture for c# application which reads Excel

Tags: c#, excel, locale, cultureinfo, culture

I am reading Excel file by using OLEDBConnection in C#.

I want to change current thread culture as per culture of Excel file so I can get dates in culture specific formats. I have used following code but it is not working. It still converts date to us English format. If I change Format from `Control Panel --> Region and Language` then it works:

[image: See screen shot]

My Code:

```
public static System.Data.DataTable GetWorksheet(string worksheetName, string connectionString)
{
   try
   {
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ", true);
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
      OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
      OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(
      //"select * from [" + worksheetName + "]", con);
      "select * from [" + worksheetName + "$]", con);

      con.Open();
      System.Data.DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
      cmd.Fill(excelDataSet);
      con.Close();
      con.Dispose();
      System.Data.DataTable dt = excelDataSet.Tables[0];
      if (excelDataSet != null)
         excelDataSet.Dispose();

      return dt;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      throw e;
   }
}
```

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();` looks suspicious. Try to comment that out

Comment: Looks like your problem is `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ", true);`
Use overload `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");` because Boolean suggests that you should use culture from user settings on your machine... I believe

Answer (score 0):

Check out the examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) from Microsoft.  They use:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
```

Comment: `CurrentUICulture` is for resource manager, not need that in this case